# laravel sub domain routing shows page without route entry

Tags: php, laravel-5

i have a domain www.asdasd.com where i am using laravel. there are couple of routing (b,c,d) there. i also have a subdomain here demo.asdasd.com where route is (b,c).

now my problem is if someone want to go demo.asdasd.com/d it shows the user page for www.asdasd.com/d but i didn't wrote anu route for this url. i don't want to show any pages that i did not give route for that subdomain.

my routes file is something like the following,

```
Route::group(['domain'=>'demo.asdasd.com'], function(){
    Route::get('/', 'baseController@ud');
    Route::get('b', 'baseController@b2');
    Route::get('c', 'baseController@c2');
});


Route::get('/', 'PageController@index');
Route::get('b', 'PageController@b');
Route::get('c', 'PageController@c');
Route::get('d', 'PageController@d');
```

thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
Route::group(['domain'=>'demo.asdasd.com'], function(){
    Route::get('/', 'baseController@ud');
    Route::get('b', 'baseController@b2');
    Route::get('c', 'baseController@c2');
});

Route::group(['domain'=>'www.asdasd.com'], function(){
   Route::get('/', 'PageController@index');
   Route::get('b', 'PageController@b');
   Route::get('c', 'PageController@c');
   Route::get('d', 'PageController@d');
});
```

Comment: If you don't mention a group domain, all route is reachable

Comment: thanks for the solution.
if somebody try to access with asdasd.com(without www) will it take him to  the main site??